# Unable to connect to postgresql server using local ip address

Tags: python, postgresql, localhost, port

I'm using python & postgresql, I have setup a server to run python scripts which inserts data into my postgresql db. However, I've only ever used localhost before to connect to my db and now i assume i'll need to use my IP address(?) as the host for the params to connect, along with the dbname,username,password & port. So I'm testing out (locally) to see if using my local IP address works before it goes live on the server, but I cannot get postgresql working at all. This is the error I receive:

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "86.xx.xx.xxx", port 5432 failed: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060)
        Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

I have tried the following:

- modify postgresql.conf file to `listen_addresses = '*'`
- modify pg_hba.conf to add `host    all             all             86.xx.xx.xxx/32       md5`
- opened port (5432) connection using windows firewall, when i type `netstat -an |find /i "5432"` into the command i get the below output:

  TCP    0.0.0.0:5432           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING

  TCP    [::]:5432              [::]:0                 LISTENING

Does anyone have any idea to what the issue could be? Thanks (this is the first time I've encountered something like this so it might sound stupid)

Comment: *Connection timed out* would indicate that the remote host has a firewall preventing access to port `5432`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver in my command, i typed: "netsh firewall show state" and it gives me this output: 
Port   Protocol  Version  Program
5432   TCP       Any      (null)

so it is open, but whether it's connnected to my postgresql im not sure

Comment: Do you have Postgres configured to accept connections both on the local and the public IP addresses?

Comment: @TimRoberts yes so in my config files the problem still persists whether the "listen_addresses" is "*" or "localhost, 86.xx.xx.xxx"

Comment: Next step.  Is this computer literally connected to the internet as 86.xx.xx.xx, or is there a router doing port forwarding?

Comment: @TimRoberts Yup my computer is connected to the internet with that IP

Comment: Just realized you said this: *. So I'm testing out (locally) to see if using my local IP address works  ...*.  Then you commented: *... my computer is connected to the internet with that IP*. So the internet maybe seeing that IP, but the local client is not.  You would need to test from a machine outside the server host.

Comment: If you use 127.0.0.1 as the IP, does your Python script connect?

Comment: This is a networking issue, a firewall is interfering with your access.  The firewall which is doing it is presumably the one on your router, not on your local machine.  Once you go out to your router (or beyond) and try to come back again, you are subject to the same rules as anyone else would be.

Comment: @TimRoberts yes using that IP connects successfully

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I've tried on a seperate server which has a different IP address than the server host and still get the same response

Comment: Then as @jjanes commented this is a firewall issue. You will need to determine what is on the network between the outside world and your server and verify the firewall settings on each device.